# sql oracle using update

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to take data from one table to add to another table.

I got **two** SQL's:

```
SQL1:

select * from table1;

SQL2:

select * from table2 where coloumn1 = table1.coloumn6 (number)
```

## table1 looks like:

[image]

For better understanding we call each coloumn `coloumn1, coloumn2, ... coloumn9`

## table2 looks like:

[image]

For better understanding we call each coloumn `coloumn1, coloumn2, ... coloumn13`

## What should happen in text

My SQL has to take the value from `table1.coloumn6` (number) - checking if this value is given in `table2.coloumn1`

```
select * from table2 where coloumn1 = table1.coloumn6 (SQL2)
```

If yes it should `update` the data from `table1.coloumn2` (varchar2) to `table2.coloumn4` (varchar2).

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it tout. Did you have a qusetion?

Comment: My question is how to solve this - any ideas or usefull tips.

Comment: you can try merge statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to update `table1.column2` to the corresponding value in `table2.column1` based on other conditions.  Based on your description:

```
update table1
    column2 = (select column4 from table2 t2 where t2.column1 = table1.column6)
    where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.column1 = table1.column6);
```

Comment: I need the data from table1 in table2. What I wanted to say is that I need the data in table1.coloumn2 transfer to table2.coloum4. But my SQL should be only allowed to do this if table1.coloum6 = table2.coloum1

Comment: I am sorry for my English which makes it hard for you to understand

Answer (score 1):

MERGE is good for updating/inserting tables based on other tables. Something like this should work (would be a bit more clear with distinctly-named columns). It also accepts an optional 'WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN' clause which lets you insert new records.

```
MERGE INTO table2
USING (SELECT column2, column6 FROM table1) table1
ON (table2.column1 = table1.column6)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  update set column4 = column2;
```